# Strategy for accessing data in multi-tenant environment with Spring and Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, multi-tenant, synchronized

I am working in a multi-tenant environment where data can be accessed from about 10 different datasources (and entitymanagers) with a webapplication (rest) frontend.

The entitymanager to be used is depending on a URL parameter in the rest api, ex.  api/orders/**1**/1000003.

I need to use entitymanager "1" to fetch the data.  At the moment I am using a method in the repository layer where I call setDistrict(1), before creating a hibernate session and creating a query via hibernate Criteria.

All is working fine, but I am worried about the fact that the method will need to be synchronized to avoid getting data from a wrong entitymanager.
When I synchronize the repository method I am worried that the performance will be horrible..

What is the good strategy for implementing this multi-tenant access so performance is good and the correct data will be returned under heavy load as well?

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SessionFactory of Hibernate allows to use a [tenancy behavior](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html#d5e4780):

> - **SCHEMA**   Correlates to the separate schema approach. It is an error to attempt to open a session without a tenant identifier using
>     this strategy. Additionally, a
>     org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.spi.MultiTenantConnectionProvider
>     must be specified.
> - **DATABASE**   Correlates to the separate database approach. It is an error to attempt to open a session without a tenant identifier
>     using this strategy. Additionally, a
>     org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.spi.MultiTenantConnectionProvider
>     must be specified.
> - **DISCRIMINATOR**   Correlates to the partitioned (discriminator) approach. It is an error to attempt to open a session without a tenant
>     identifier using this strategy. This strategy is not yet implemented
>     in Hibernate as of 4.0 and 4.1. Its support is planned for 5.0.

In your case I think you need **SCHEMA** or **DATABASE** and have to implement the *MultiTenantConnectionProvider* ([source](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html#d5e4866)).

```
/**
 * Simplisitc implementation for illustration purposes supporting 2 hard coded providers (pools) and leveraging
 * the support class {@link org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.spi.AbstractMultiTenantConnectionProvider}
 */
public class MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl extends AbstractMultiTenantConnectionProvider {
    private final ConnectionProvider acmeProvider = ConnectionProviderUtils.buildConnectionProvider( "acme" );
    private final ConnectionProvider jbossProvider = ConnectionProviderUtils.buildConnectionProvider( "jboss" );

    @Override
    protected ConnectionProvider getAnyConnectionProvider() {
        return acmeProvider;
    }

    @Override
    protected ConnectionProvider selectConnectionProvider(String tenantIdentifier) {
        if ( "acme".equals( tenantIdentifier ) ) {
            return acmeProvider;
        }
        else if ( "jboss".equals( tenantIdentifier ) ) {
            return jbossProvider;
        }
        throw new HibernateException( "Unknown tenant identifier" );
    }
}
```

For more details see the linked documentation.